# Enable TLS for mongodb inside EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using mongodb running inside docker in AWS EC2 instance.
I can connect directly to my mongodb by using EC2 instance's IP address : `mongosh "mongodb://<publicIp>:27017"`.
Because this connection is not secure, I want to enable TLS encryption for mongodb connection.
Can you tell me how to do that ? Can I use my domain for mongodb endpoint with TLS enable ? 
(Ex: `db.example.com:27017` instead of `<public ip>:27017`)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow [the documentation for configuring TLS on Mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/). Specifically, add the following to your Mongodb configuration:

```
net:
   ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
```

The client must also [connect using TLS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#std-label-ssl-client-connection-only):

```
mongosh --ssl --host db.example.com --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/caToValidateServerCertificates.pem
```

Note the following statement from the documentation:

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, when performing comparison of SAN, MongoDB supports comparison of DNS names or IP addresses. In previous versions, MongoDB only supports comparisons of DNS names.

Thus you can use either DNS name or IP address so long as it is in the SAN of the TLS certificate.